# RTK Query типизация axiosBaseQuery

Tags: typescript

Есть такой базовый запрос:

```
export const axiosBaseQuery = ({baseUrl = '', headers}: IAxiosBaseQuery): BaseQueryFn<IBaseQuery, unknown, unknown> => {
    return async ({url, params, method, data}) => {
        try {
            const result = await axios({
                url: baseUrl + url,
                method: method,
                ...(params && {params: params}),
                ...(headers && {headers: headers({})}),
                ...(data && {data: data}),
                responseType: 'json'
            });
            return {
                data: result.data
            };
        } catch (axiosError) {
            const err = axiosError as AxiosError;
            return {
                error: {status: err.response?.status, data: err.response?.data}
            };
        }
    };
};
```

и есть объявление (пародия) на интерсепторы:

```
export const APIBaseQueryInterceptor = axiosBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    headers: (headers) => {
        const token = 'test';
        if (token) {
            headers['authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        return headers;
    }
});

export const APIBaseQuery: BaseQueryFn<IBaseQuery, unknown, unknown> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    const result = await APIBaseQueryInterceptor(args, api, extraOptions);

    if (result.error && result.error.status === 404) {
        // try to get a new token
        //const refreshResult = await APIBaseQueryInterceptor('/refreshToken', api, extraOptions);
        console.log('test');
        if (false) {
            // store the new token
            //api.dispatch(tokenReceived(refreshResult.data));
            // retry the initial query
            //result = await APIBaseQueryInterceptor(args, api, extraOptions);
        } else {
            //api.dispatch(loggedOut());
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

и в `APIBaseQuery` когда я проверяю на ошибку, `result.error.status === 404`, он мне выдает на `result.error`:

```
TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

когда я вызываю генерик, таким образом: `BaseQueryFn<IBaseQuery, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError>`, ошибка пропадает... но начинает ругатся на `return async ({url, params, method, data})...` в `axiosBaseQuery` со следующим текстом:

```
TS2322: Type '({ url, params, method, data }: IBaseQuery) => Promise<{ data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'BaseQueryFn<IBaseQuery, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, {}>'.   Type 'Promise<{ data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>>'.     Type 'Promise<{ data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>>'.       Types of property 'then' are incompatible.         Type '<TResult1 = { data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | und...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.           Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.             Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.               Type '{ data: any; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>'.                 Type '{ error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}>'.                   Type '{ error: { status: number | undefined; data: any; }; data?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ error?: undefined; data: unknown; meta?: {} | undefined; }'.                     Types of property 'error' are incompatible.                       Type '{ status: number | undefined; data: any; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

Вроде все по документации сделал, но не могу понять где я что то упускаю...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
interface BaseError {
    code: string | number;
    message: string;
    details: string[];
}

export const axiosBaseQuery = ( { baseUrl }: { baseUrl: string } = { baseUrl: '' } ): BaseQueryFn<{
    url: string
    method: Method
    data?: AxiosRequestConfig['data']
    params?: AxiosRequestConfig['params']
},
    unknown,
    BaseError> =>
    async ( { url, method, data, params } ) => {
        try {
            const result = await axios( { url: baseUrl + url, method, data, params } )
            return { data: result.data }
        } catch ( axiosError: any ) {
            let err = axiosError as AxiosError<BaseError>
            const error: BaseError = {
                code: err.response?.data?.code || err.response?.status || '',
                message: err.response?.data?.message || err?.message || 'Неизвестная ошибка',
                details: err.response?.data?.details || []
            }
            return { error }

        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]